# How do I check the most recent change in my application's Geofences? (Windows Phone 8.1RT)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

My application can create several geofences but I only need to check the status of the geofence which was last changed.
i.e. If the user travels from Geofence A into Geofence B, I need the application to recognize that the user has left A just after he does and similarly for when the user enters Geofence B. However, there are   several other Geofences (C,D,E) as well.

I'm using the ReadReport method of the GeofenceMonitor inside an event handler. However this gives me an exception when I'm using the Last() method of the list.

This code sample  uses a loop to iterate through each of the reports in the list and as mentioned before I'm only concerned with the most recent change.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn322030.aspx

This is the code I'm trying to implement

`ReportList = sender.ReadReports();`

`LastReport = ReportList.Last();`
where

```
private GeofenceStateChangeReport LastReport;
private IReadOnlyList<GeofenceStateChangeReport> ReportList;
```

are my variables
and `sender` is of type `GeofenceMonitor`